# What to recite for asking forgiveness?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, tawba, forgiveness

There is a Hadith in Abu dawood that says, "If anyone continually asks pardon, Allah will appoint for him a way out of every distress, and a relief from every anxiety, and will provide for him from where he did not reckon.”
My question is, in what way one should ask pardon? By reciting what exactly? Did our prophet (sa) suggested in what way we should seek pardon in this Hadith?

Answer (score -1):

The first and simple way is just be ashamed and regretful. Say sorry from your heart to god. Cry and be sorry. Then promise to don't do that bad work ever never. And try to do good things for compensate.

Actually god is very kind and generous. So just be ashamed, cry and say sorry then promised and compensate. :-) Be optimistic :-)